# Excel: Find() specific number format

Tags: microsoft-excel, microsoft-excel-2007

I want to determine if a cell has one of these number formats within the cell:

```
###.##
###
###.#
```

Example:

```
048.4
```

The data is most likely a string, as it came from a PDF.

I'm trying to use `Find()` but it doesn't appear to accept regex.

What's the best solution for this, while trying to avoid 3rd party plugins?

Answer (score 0):

One way would be to use the formula `=CELL("format",A1)` for each cell of interest (changing `A1` accordingly) which after the F shows the number of decimal places. (But I'm not sure how you got your example to start and display  `0`!)

Comment: The data came from Adobe's "Save As Excel" feature.

Comment: Yes but that'll still match on sentences with periods in them, which this file contains.

Comment: The cell contains more than just those numbers though, it also can contain text (which is why I said the cell "contains" and not "equals")

Answer (score 0):

1. To identify your format it is sufficient to give the number of digits after decimal separator. To do this you can use formulas pasted in colums B and C
   [image]
2. To force Excel to treat data in a cell as number you can perform any numerical operation on the cell. Try e.g. adding zero, or multiplying by 1. It will only work if in your locale decimal separator is the same as in text, `.` in your case. If it isn't you need to replace dots with commas. In the above example, I replace the dot with comma. If you don't need to, just add zero to input value in column A.